# polymer elements not behaving correct, paper-button always on top, paper-shadow only during animation

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

Any idea whats going wrong here?

I am trying to use paper-shadow.

you can see on the lowest box I have shadow (thats just css), but for the blue and black bordered box I try to use paper shadow. .. no luck..

during the core-animation switch from one section to another, I see the shadow 
but as soon as the animation is over, the shadow is gone.
[image]

[image]

additionally it seems that my green border paper-buttons, create and cancel, are always on top of everything. I dont set any z-index as far as I know??

they should be hidden underneath the black bordered card.

code can be found here

[blue marked box](http://github.com/HannesRammer/Dartabase/blob/master/dartabase_migration/web/poly/createMigration.html)
or
[black marked box](http://github.com/HannesRammer/Dartabase/blob/master/dartabase_migration/web/poly/createMigrationTable.html)
**UPDATE:
[simple example](http://github.com/HannesRammer/paper_button_and_shadow)**

just run web/toolt/index.html click on create migration then create table

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a minimal example that allows to reproduce this issue.

Comment: can get a simple example here
**https://github.com/HannesRammer/paper_button_and_shadow** just run web/toolt/index.html click on **create migration** then **create table**

Comment: As mentioned at https://github.com/dart-lang/paper-elements/issues/47 the links don't work.

Comment: deam my fault open now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned at github.com/dart-lang/paper-elements/issues/47

update to 
polymer >=0.14.0 <0.15.0

- core_elements >=0.2.1+1 <0.3.0
- paper_elements >=0.2.0 <0.3.0

will fix both issues thx